# MVC - Html.BeginForm. My action method does not recieve argument

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to save data to my model.
Here is my Action method for doing that:

```
...   

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateSectionInformation(SectionInformation sectionInformation) {
            ViewBag.SectionUpdatedSuccesfully = true;
            SectionInformation s = sectionInformation;
            // Save settings to database.
            using (var session = MvkStorage.GetSession()) {
                var client = new MvkSectionStorageHandler(session);
                try {
                    client.SaveOrUpdateSection(s.Section);                   

                    client.SaveOrUpdateSectionReschedulingRelations(s.RescheduleFromRelations);
                    client.SaveOrUpdateSectionReschedulingRelations(s.RescheduleToRelations);
                } catch (Exception) {
                    ViewBag.SectionUpdatedSuccesfully = false;
                }
            }

            return View("Index", s);
        }
```

Here is the Html.BefinForm "declaration" (the controller name is SectionController):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("UpdateSectionInformation", "Section", FormMethod.Post)) {
```

It seems like the problem is that the UpdateSectionInformation get an empty model. How should I solve that? I am new to MVC and I really don´t get where UpdateSectionInformation is called.
I have seen something about Html.HiddenFor, should I use that here?:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RescheduleFromRelations.Count(); i++ ) {


                var relation = Model.RescheduleFromRelations.ElementAt(i);
                var relationId = relation.FromSection.ToString() + relation.ToSection.ToString();
                ...
```

Edit: Problem solved thanks to comment

Comment: `UpdateSectionInformation()` is called when you submit the form (click a submit button). If your model is `null` its because you are not generating the correct name attributes for the properties of the model.

Comment: Yeah, well I understand that pressing the save button sets things in motion, but thats it. But anyway, you are correct! Thank so so much